# Creating php xml listener and listening.Having trouble in responding back an XML

Tags: php, xml, listener, respond-to

I am using a third party API in the system which post xml data to my URL which I get and process the xml. They are saying server has to reply back as Accepted.
I am having trouble in this part.

Example:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' )
{
    //Read the xmlinput and write to the file
    $xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
   //...processing the xml and storing to my SQL...

   //How to reply back as '<xml>Accepted</xml>'

}
```

Please need help.I am able to process xml file and get the data but having sending them back xml reply.

Note:API post results to URL. My server should respond with "Accepted" if successful

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$element = $dom->createElement('xml', 'Accepted');
$dom->appendChild($element);
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: can i echo it without header.I have already Header in that page

Comment: i am still having the issue as i tried to echo without header.Please help

Comment: Do you have xml header? What is your error, what is you API? We cannot help you if you did not share all information.

Comment: my application has runs on concrete 5 framework.So it has default header and footer from concrete 5.How to echo just this one on that page.